# Linux/Windows: Keyboard stopped working at boot for no reason I have to plug/unplug to have it to work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, keyboard, grub

Suddenly without any reason my usb keyboard stopped working at boot. I can't use it, I have to plug/unplug to make it to work. I didn't add or change any hardware component, no update or whatever, it's the same as yesterday as it worked as no problems (and of the past days too).
I tried to change usb port too but it's the same.

Just as test neither the capsock button works (I don't see the light on/off) so the keyboard is completely off.
I have an MSI motherboard, pressing delete, or F1 before booting the system or other keys doesn't have any effect.
If I plug/unplug the keyboard it works and it keep working across reboots but not if I shutdown the system.

I have a dual boot system linux(ubuntu) and windows so at boot it starts grub and linux by default on linux boot I read these errors:

```
[    3.319738] usb 1-7: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[    3.447712] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    3.447903] usb 1-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[    3.655878] usb 1-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[    3.863709] usb 1-7: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[    3.863939] usb usb1-port7: unable to enumerate USB device
```

A very strange fact is that if instead of booting linux I boot on windows (plug/unplug keyboard on grub to change system to boot) the keyboard works as I said after a plug/unplug but after I shudown windows system it works on the next boot too!  this is very strange!
If I boot on ubuntu it doesn't work on the next shutdown/boot.

I have to say that I have tested with other two keyboards and I don't have this problem, my current keyboard is a Finco Majestouch 2.
Keyboard broken? but it seems strange.

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE 1:

If I connect to the usb port an usb hub (I have the Ultra Mini Hub USB 2.0 from Amazon) and I connect to it the keyboard it works at boot now, very strange.

UPDATE 2:

Testing and searching online I found this:

https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error

The solution works (when it says to turn off pc in my case is to unplug power supply too) and on a new boot keyboard is recognized.
But it's not a definitive solution, it may happen that it get not recognized again.
Still with the (unpowered) hub I have no problems.
I am not convinced what could be happened because it worked before... maybe as someone answered/commented an hardware problem for sure then.

Comment: [This is likely a power issue. What other devices do you have attached?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/456947/error-32-while-establishing-usb-connection)

Comment: the keyboard, the mouse on usb, nothing else. I have 2 nvme drive, no dedicated graphic card.

Comment: This still doesn't explain why with the usb hub between keyboard and port it works, and the weird fact that if I boot on windows and shutdown on the next boot it works.

Comment: Try another keyboard.

Comment: Did it as I wrote, and it works.

Comment: I assume the USB hub is externally powered.

Comment: It is not, it's a simple usb hub to ad some ports but not externally powered.

Answer (score 0):

As another keyboard works, this problem is specific to this keyboard
and is a hardware problem, not software.

If you can't live with this problem, then you need to replace the keyboard.
Keyboards are not worth repairing (if you can even find someone to repair it).

Comment: As I said in another comment, I can agree with a keyboard harware problem but this still doesn't explain why with the usb hub between keyboard and port it works (not an externally powered one), and the weird fact that if I boot on windows and shutdown on the next boot it works

Comment: To answer this would take an electrical engineer to study the circuits and find the failure point. Electrical problems can behave weirdly and their solution is always to replace the parts - no one fixes them any more.